# Android Studio: Core app with different wrapper for every customer

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an app which is to be offered to many different potential customers. The idea is to create a core app which has all the functionality and activities, but which does not stand alone.

Another project will be the a wrapper project which will have a config JSON string and the styling that the final apk will have. No functionality.

The core app will be a dependency in the wrapper app.

This is an existing app which is developed in Eclipse by someone else and is designed exactly as described. I'm supposed to build it again in Android Studio and modernize the UI with the latest trends.

My question is: What should the core app be? Should it be a 'library'? a module? a normal app project maybe? if it's a normal app, would it be possible to attach it to the wrapper app which is also an app project just without activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built both types of apps - apps that share and require a core library, but have different UI implementations and apps that have all the core functionality built-in, and then separate apps that modify the "look and feel" of the core app. In both cases, all activities are in the "core" app and none are in the "wrapper" or helper apps.

The biggest issue here is the "dependency" on the core app. Do you want to maintain and market the "core app" as a flagship product, while the other "apps" are really just "themes" for the core app? Or are you wanting to maintain and market a suite of apps, without really having a core or flagship app?

If you create the core "app" as a library, you have to remember that there are a few restrictions on library projects. For example, you cannot use a "CASE" statement if it uses "R.java" resources because the `R.java` file is built at compile time, and `case` statements cannot be constructed on subsequent 'R.java`dependencies. (You can convert to`if-else` pretty easily though, in most cases.) You may find that the conversion has restrictions that you cannot avoid and that cause flaws, but usually re-designing the implementation will circumvent any such problems. In other words, you make have to work hard to get it done, but you should be able to do it.

EDIT:

If you create a project library, then any changes you make to the library will be reflected in the "wrapper" apps the next time you build them. This is great because it makes it easy to update "all apps" - but it's terrible for regression testing. In other words, after any update to the library, you may need to test every app (which is boring) because there may be exceptions in any one of them. However, a strict adherence to design and coding can help reduce or eliminate this. I've just found that actually testing each app is about the only way to avoid problems unless the "wrapper" apps are very simple and well defined, which is very rare.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, The Core app will never be on its own and will always be a dependency on the Wrapper app. That means that the wrapper app is actually the main app and the core app will be a library. Every apk will be styled to a specific customer likings and will have the JSON string with config that matches that customers needs.

Comment: I answered the question for both cases because other users may interpret your question differently or may have a similar use case, but it requires a different approach. Also, it seems like you need a library project and you should be able to build it. But creating a library has some limitations that may result in either a substantial overhaul of your design or an inherent limitation that cannot be circumvented.

Comment: I will update the core project and would like the wrapper project to always have the updated reference, the same way it's been done in the old app in Eclipse. How would I go about adding a reference of the core project to the wrapper project? If I try through the 'Project structure' dialog, I can only add modules INTO the existing wrapper, but not a reference to an outside living library project...

Comment: I edited my response. Updates to the library will be reflected in new builds in the wrapper app - for better or for worse...

Comment: That's great and exactly the behavior I need. My problem now is just how to do practically do it i n Android studio. Can you guide me to some links on how to create/define a library in AS and how to reference it to another project?

Comment: Your question was about how to approach your problem. For your "new question" you can find a lot of references if you search "android studio create library" or do similar searches. A lot of people have already answered that question, I don't think I can contribute anything new there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making most of your application into a library project. Then the original application and the new one would be new projects that depend on the library and would define their own app-specific resources.

Comment: so you say that a library project can contain Activities?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't they?

Comment: Just asking. I'm new to Android Studio.