# Android Studio: Add library as reference, not as import

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

This question is a sequel to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762355/android-studio-core-app-with-different-wrapper-for-every-customer).

In an existing Eclipse solution I have a library project which is used as a Android Dependency in the main app project. That means that if I edit this library, and compile, the main project is updated with the latest from that library.

I'm trying to do the same in Android Studio. That means not importing a library, but using it as a reference or dependency in the app project. I've been trying for two days now with no luck. Help is HIGHLY appreciated.

**build.gradle** (of the app project - there is nothing interesting her as I didn't change it much)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Please post your build config files.

Comment: build.gradle code posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this steps:

1. Download library
2. File/import module
3. Select your library and rename :LibraryName
4. Go to build.gradle and write.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
......
compile project(':LibraryName')
.....
}
```

Then if you import module you can edit library and proyect its updated

Answer (score 1):

Say you have 2 projects, 1 application and 1 library project, you want to push all your external dependencies to your library project, so your application project only depends on the library project:

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
include ':library'
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
}
```

**library/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'external-dependencies-1'
    compile 'external-dependencies-2'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hidro. I used 'com.android.library' because 'android-library' is deprecated.